# how to combine 4D xarray data

Tags: python, python-xarray, atmosphere

I have a 4D xarray which contains time, lev, lat, and lon. The data is for specific day so that the length of time is 1. My goal is to use 4D xarray with same attributess but include a month data so that the time length will be 30.

I try to google it but cannot find useful information. I appreciate it if anyone can provide some insights.

[image]

Comment: how are you hoping to get monthly data from a single data point? do you want to simply repeat the data for each day in 2018-08? Which days do you want in the result? All August 2018 days?

Comment: Thanks for the question! The current data is in a fomart of data(time, lev, lat, lon) from each file. The length of time is 1 for each file since each file represents 1 day data. I don't expect to get a monthly from a single file. I am hopling to compile all august days into one data array so that the lengh of time will be 31. Hope it make sense!

Comment: oh - do you have one file for each day? in that case, simply using [`xr.concat`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html) or [`xr.open_mfdataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html) with `dim='time'` should do the trick!

Comment: the fact that you have many files and are hoping to combine them into a time series is super important context for your question - for next time - try to make sure all of the relevant info is in the question description so we don't get too far off track ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple points in a time series, you can use [`xr.DataArray.resample`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.resample.html) to change the frequency of a datetime dimension. Once you have resampled, you'll get a DataArrayResample object, to which you can apply any of the methods listed in the [DataArrayResample API docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.03.0/generated/xarray.core.resample.DatasetResample.html).

If you only have a single point in time, you can't resample to a higher frequency. Your best bet is probably to simply select and drop the time dim altogether, then use [`expand_dims`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html) to expand the dimensions again to include the full time dim you want. Just be careful because this overwrites the time dimension's values with whatever you want, regardless of what was in there before:

```py
target_dates = pd.date_range('2018-08-01', '2018-08-30', freq='D')

daily = (
    da
    .isel(time=0, drop=True)
    .expand_dims(time=target_dates)
)
```